# Why are my datagrid crashing my browser when sorting them

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I have a silverlight application and use some datagrids in it.

My problem (crash) happens whenever I'm sorting the datagrid using the left click on any coloumn header.

I've already tried to debug but the debugger doesn't stop when the crash happens even if I select all the exceptions in the VS exception options.

I tried remove all columns but one, without a format. Nothing better.

And I don't know where the problem comes from (the datagrid, the datasource...).

So I will show the code that I think is responsible for this, but I'm not sure if there will be something missing.

```
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"

    <riaControls:DomainDataSource x:Name="DataSource"
                                  QueryName="GetListCriteres"
                                  AutoLoad="False">
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            <domain:DomainServiceGlobal />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
    </riaControls:DomainDataSource>
  <my:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ElementName=DataSource, Mode=TwoWay}"
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
ToolTipService.ToolTip="Liste des périodes"
Grid.Row="0"
HorizontalAlignment="Left"
x:Name="dgData" 
Margin="20,0,20,0"
IsReadOnly="True"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
  <my:DataGrid.Columns>
      <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Date de début"
                             Binding="{Binding DateDebPer,Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy}" />
      <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Date de fin"
                             Binding="{Binding DateFinPer,Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy}" />
      </my:DataGrid.Columns>
 </my:DataGrid>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=dgData, Path=SelectedItem}" 
      Grid.Row="1">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid Grid.Row="0">
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                     Margin="0,15,0,0">
            <TextBlock x:Name="HeaderElementData" 
                       Margin="5,5,5,5"  />
        </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
  <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
              Orientation="Vertical">
     <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <!-- 1ere ligne -->
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
            Margin="5,5,5,5"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0">
 <sdk:Label Target="{Binding ElementName=dpDateDebPer}" 
            Width="110"
            Grid.Column="0" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Margin="2,0,0,0" />
<mydatepicker:MyCustomDatePicker Width="130"
                                 Name="dpDateDebPer" 
                                 SelectedDate="{Binding DateDebPer, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" />
<sdk:DescriptionViewer Grid.Column="2"
                       Margin="5,0,0,0"
                       Target="{Binding ElementName=dpDateDebPer}"
                       Visibility="Visible"/>
</StackPanel>
<sdk:ValidationSummary x:Name="vsListeErreursData" 
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="6"
                       Grid.Row="5" 
                       MaxHeight="100" 
                       BorderThickness="0" />
</Grid>
</StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I don't understand why a sort crash my brower, it is just a sort after all...

Is this the xaml code?

Is it something else?

I don't understand because, the data are correctly loaded and displays the first time, but only when I left click on any column header to sort the `datagrid`, there is a crash.

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried to debug? http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/cc838267(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: @RobsonFilhoColodeti  I am running on debug mode. And when it crahs, it does not go to the VS, it just crash. And without knowing what could possibly go wrong, I can't put a break point where it is needed.

Comment: did you check all the exception types in the visual studio exception options? (check here how to do it if you don't know how to) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712785/vs-express-2013-for-windows-does-not-halt-at-the-async-line-that-throws-an-exc/26713118#26713118

Comment: @RobsonFilhoColodeti I activated all exceptions, my browser still crash wuthout going through an exception...

Comment: do all the columns sorting crash? or is it just a specific column?

Comment: @RobsonFilhoColodeti yes, all columns crash. I also thinked at start, it was just one, but I tested one by one, and they all crash.

Comment: i would try to remove all the formatting stuff and leave the data just as you get it from the database(or whatever else) to check if it is something like that, leaving the grids as simple as possible and then checking if the sorting still crashes, this is some kind of troubleshooting to try to find the problem. then post your results =)